# Table column expand when expanding input, why?

Tags: html, css

```
<form action="insertshop.php" method="post" id="insertform" autocomplete="off">
<div id="papertable_insert">
<table class="papertable"><tr>
<td class="s">
<select style="width:100px;" name="pshop_id" id="pshop_id">
            <option value=""></option>
</select>
</td>
<td class="n" style="background-color:#0F0"><input type="text" name="shopname" id="shopname" size="90"/></td>
<td class="m" style="background-color:#036"><input type="text" name="shopname" id="shopname" size="1"/></td>
<td class="a">Add</td>
</tr></table>
</div>
</form>
```

by increasing the size of the input, table column expands knowing that a lot of white space exists in the column which means the input size didn't exceed the Column width. Any ideas?

The css :

```
#papertable_insert{
    width:860px;
    height:30px;
    margin:10px auto;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;

}

#papertable_insert input, #papertable_insert input select{
    margin:0px;


}

table.papertable{
    width:860px;

}

td.s{width:130px;}
td.n{width:660px;}
td.m{width:70px;}
td.a{width:40px;}
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle for everyone to have a play with: http://jsfiddle.net/Jxyd4/

Comment: Um, what are you asking? By the way, your four table cells add up to be more width than the table itself: 130 + 660 + 70 + 40 = 900px > 860px.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Thanks, that was the mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from comment:

Your table cells add up to be more than the table itself:
130 (s) + 660 (n) + 70 (m) + 40 (a) = 900, where the table is only specified to have `width: 860px`.